# JQuery conditional formatting based on hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came by a script by @Stofke ([original jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/Ya68Q/)) for using JQuery for conditional formatting on a HTML Table.

I have been trying to tweak this script so that the score is based on a hidden form field (see below), but when I do, I only get one colour showing, rather than than the different colour scales.

```
$(function() {
    $('tr> td').each(function(index) {
        var scale = [['vPoor', 10], ['poor', 50], ['avg', 250], ['good', 1250], ['vGood', 6250]];
        var score = $('input.sf').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            if (score <= scale[i][1]) {
                $('input.sf').closest('tr').addClass(scale[i][0]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I am sure it is a rookie error, but if someone could please point the error out to me that would be great.

HTML table structure

```
<table>
    <col id="name" />
    <col id="score" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Allan, Paul</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bartlett, James</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="60"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Callow, Simon</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="35"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dennis, Mark</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="289"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ennals, Simon</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="1020"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finnegan, Seamus</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" class="sf" value="5648"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the reason for removing the `:odd` selector?

Comment: I didn't think it was required as I wanted the conditional formatting acrossnall columns.

Comment: You still need the `:odd` selector as that is where your values are coming from. You can style the entire row (across all columns) with what you did by using `.closest('tr')`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Can you provide us with the structure of your HTML? We're guessing here cause we have no clue what we're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the following line:

```
var score = $('input.sf').val();
```

That gets the value of the first `<input>` element with the class "sf". I assume you have such an element for each row. You need to get the one in the row, not the first one.

Something like the following might work, but it assumes the `<input>` element is a descendant of the `<td>` element. If that is not correct, you might need to change it a bit.

```
var score = $(this).find('input.sf').val();
```

---

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4cpusju/2/) with a few other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your trying to do:

```
$(function() {
$('tr> td:odd').each(function(index) {//added back the :odd selector
    var scale = [['vPoor', 10], ['poor', 50], ['avg', 250], ['good', 1250], ['vGood', 6250]];
    var score = $(this).html();//referenced this instead of input.sf
    for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
        if (score <= scale[i][1]) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass(scale[i][0]);//referenced this instead of input.sf
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Should explain changes made so people don't have to scan for differences

Comment: @JoseRodrigues Thanks but this doesn't show any conditional formatting

Comment: where will this input be in your table? @JonathanGriffin

Comment: I have added the table structure to my original question.